# Defining minoccurs and max occurs in WSDL using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wsdl

I have generated WSDL with complex types using action webservice in rails.

Now I need to add minoccurs and maxoccurs in complex type definitions using ruby on rails

Defined complex type in API file(SampleApi.rb).

Any suggestions on adding min and maxoccurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped all needed arguments by ActionWebService::Simple classes

example

```
class SoapRequestComplex <  ActionWebService::Struct     
end

TelephoneNumber < ActionWebService::Simple
    base :string
end

class SoapRequest < SoapRequestComplex
  member :number, TelephoneNumberInfo, :nillable => true, :minOccurs => 0
end
```